# find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively | is there anyway to achieve this using window function?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively:
I am looking for a query to achieve this result using a window function rather than making a self join

Logs table:

```
+----+-----+
| Id | Num |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 1   |
| 2  | 1   |
| 3  | 1   |
| 4  | 2   |
| 5  | 1   |
| 6  | 2   |
| 7  | 2   |
+----+-----+
```

Result table:

```
+-----------------+
| ConsecutiveNums |
+-----------------+
| 1               |
+-----------------+
```

here is my query:

```
select distinct l1.num as ConsecutiveNums from logs l1
inner join logs l2 on l1.id = l2.id - 1
inner join logs l3 on l1.id = l3.id + 1
where l1.num = l2.num and l2.num = l3.num
```

but I am looking to use a window function instead

Comment: Please share what you've tried already and explain what exact problems you faced with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the value in the "previous" row and the row before that. If they're all equal to the value in the current row, you got a match. Consecutive equal numbers that are more than three would be matched more than one time like this. And a repetition of such a consecutive sequence would do so too. You can use `DISTINCT` to select them only once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       num
       FROM (SELECT num,
                    lag(num, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) = num
                    AND lag(num, 2) OVER (ORDER BY id) = num c3
                    FROM logs) x
       WHERE c3;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c10a71cda711788ea16f46d6b9a45dd2)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `ROW_NUMBER()` this way to group the consecutive numbers.

```
SELECT num as ConsecutiveNums 
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY id)
            ) AS grp
    FROM logs
    ) SQ
GROUP BY num,grp
HAVING count(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT num as ConsecutiveNums 
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY id as rw
    FROM table
    ) S
GROUP BY num,rw
HAVING count(*) >= 3
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/65457488?